# Displaying statistics: Use spider graphs?

Tags: info-visualisation, charts, graphs, statistics

Is a spider graph or progress bars better to display a set of statistics/attributes? E.g. pace, shooting accuracy, dribbling for a football player.

Comment: Hi Farbod. The question is very broad. There is a lot of theory out there on what graphs can be used with different types of data sets, and their pros and cons. Just the fact you wish to plot shooting accuracy cannot inform the type of graph to be used - what are the other dimensions? And what sort of information users would like to extract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spider graphs – radar graphs – are useful to show players statistics better than bars. The best is when they are used for data comparison, because you can visualize the *shape of a player*.
The only problem I see, is that usually for a player you have different data to show with different units measures. 
In this case the data should be *normalized* in order to get a value based on a scale (e.g. from 1 to 5).